# How to extract and sum up numbers retrieved from a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried this code so far, but I always get an Error message, saying "expected string or bytes-like object". I used the same code to extract and sum up the numbers from a local file and had no issue with it. Can somebody help me out with it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html"
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tags = soup('span')
numbers = []
for tag in tags:
    numbers.extend(re.findall(r"\d+", tag))
print(sum(int(x) for x in numbers))
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. What line is the error on? What type is the data you're passing to the function that's failing? It says str or bytes, so what is it actually?

Comment: This is the TracebackTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testing.py", line 18, in <module>
    numbers.extend(re.findall(r"\d+", tag))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `tag` to `str(tag)` in this line:

```
numbers.extend(re.findall(r"\d+", tag))
```

Because `re.findall` expects string (object of type `str`) as a second argument to match regular expression on, but `tag` is of type-class `bs4.element.Tag` which is not a subclass of `str` and needs manual conversion to string by `str(tag)` or `tag.text`. `re` module doesn't do conversion to string by itself.

Also note that `str(tag)` gives whole html of tag (e.g. `<span class="comments">25</span>`). If you need to match only text inside this tag (i.e. `25` in previous example) then instead of `str(tag)` you need to change to `tag.text`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem. Was it because python didn't recognize it as a string and therefore it needed to be clarified?

Comment: @Morv Because `re.findall` accepts only objects of type/class `str`, but you provided `tag` which is of type/class `bs4.element.Tag` which is not subclass of `str`. `re` module doesn't do conversion to `str` and you need to do that yourself using either `str(tag)` (for full html) or `tag.text` (for text inside html of tag).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The course I'm taking is very interesting but does not give very in depth explanations on how to do something or how it really works.